# Problem with CI Constructor and URI

Tags: codeigniter, constructor, continuous-integration, uri

I’m actually building a simple website with members and I wanted to display member’s page by just calling http://www.mywebsite.com/member/membername

My class member is actually working well, but I had put the code in the index function making page member accessible at http://www.mywebsite.com/member/index/membername, which is actually not really useful.

So the classic things was to put my code in the constructor, but I get the error :

404 Page Not Found
The page you requested was not found.

This is my class Member :

```
<?php

class Member extends CI_Controller {


    function __construct()
    {
           parent::__construct();


           $segment_id = $this->uri->segment(2, 0);
           echo 'segment found ='.$segment_id;
           if ($segment_id == FALSE)
            {
                   echo '- No Segment -> Printing all members ';
                   $data = array();
                   $this->layouts->set_title('Welcome!');

                   $this->layouts->add_aside('newsletter_view');

                   if($query = $this->membership_model->show_all())
                    {
                        $data['records'] = $query;
                    }

                    $this->layouts->view('show_member', $data);
            }
            else
            {
                    echo '- Segment found -> Printing the member ';
                    $data = array();
                    $this->layouts->set_title('Welcome!');

                    $this->layouts->add_aside('newsletter_view');

                    if($query = $this->membership_model->show_member())
                    {
                            $data['records'] = $query;
                    }

                    $this->layouts->view('show_member', $data);
            }

    }

}
```

And to complete, this is my model function:

```
function show_member()
    {
                echo 'model show_member working';
        $this->db->where('username', $this->uri->segment(2));
        $query = $this->db->get('members');

                return $query->result();
    }

        function show_all()
        {
                echo "model show_all working";
                $query = $this->db->get('members');
        return $query->result();
        }
```

You will find some echo into. All are perfectly working going with a url with /member or /member/segment and as I sad, all is working if I’m putting it in Index

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Answer at : http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/187548/

Answer (score 1):

Why not use routes for this?

For example, adding the route `route['member/(:any)'] = "member/index/$1";` should do the trick (haven't tested it though).